In PowerApps column chart, how ow do you deselect a selected column
I am using PowerApps charts to control a gallery. The Pie chart works fine I can select a wedge in the pie and it filters the gallery - to clear the selection all i have to do is click outside the visual. But this process does not work with a column chart. Once a column is selected in the column chart there is no way to clear the selection. I read a post and it walked me through how to clear the visual by toggling the display mode (Edit / View), but that doesn't clear the last selected value. I do not want to get into building collection if possible. I know there has to be a way to clear the value - because the Column Chart resets whenever I leave the Screen and return.

I know this is one of those nagging issues we all expect Microsoft to fix, after all it works for the pie chart so why not the column chart.
After some painful trial and error and research, I found a workaround. It all makes sense because if you navigate away from the screen that has the Chart and come back to it the selected item is deselected.
Alright so the fix, if you're using a collection is to simply add a button or icon and on the OnSelect = Clear(yourcollectionname); ClearCollect(yourcollectionname, datasource);
So basically refreshing the datasource is the fix.
And if you're using a variable, set it to blank() and the set the variable again.
Ok Microsoft, you've another open item to fix for the community!
